# detect ajax request to normal request node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

hello h have the next code and i like to know how to detect between an ajax request to a normal request? without express.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');
console.log("request.url = " + request.url);
console.log("url = "+ url);

response.setHeader('content-Type','application/json');

var filePath = '.' + request.url;
if (filePath == './')
    filePath = './index.html';

var extname = path.extname(filePath);

var contentType = 'text/html';
switch (extname) 
{
    case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
}


fs.exists(filePath, function(exists) {

    if (exists) 
    {
        fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
            if (error) 
            {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end();
            }
            else 
            {         
                console.log("contentType = "+contentType);
                response.writeHead(200, { 'content-Type': contentType });
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            }
        });
    }
    else 
    {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end();
    }
});

}).listen(8081);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8081/');
```

in the client side i send an ajax request but i ask from the browser request to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `request.headers` if it contains `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`.

If `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` has a value of `XMLHttpRequest` then it is an ajax request.

Example:

```
if (request.headers["x-requested-with"] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    //is ajax request
}
```

Comment: @user3493458 I've added a quick example.

Comment: You can probably just do `if (request.xhr) { ... }`.

Comment: @soulchild You can't, there's no `xhr` property in the native library.

Comment: Heh, sorry, I was looking for Express.js stuff and came across this. Didn't realize this wasn't part of the mix here. Nevermind then. ;-)

Comment: Apparently jQuery is necessary for this answer to work as is. I didn't catch that right away. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533435/

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles It's not necessary. The only thing jQuery does is automatically add the header. You can use any xhr library, most have added the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and I know it's old but in case someone needs the answer and the idea behind it.

Usually, on the client side, when you make an AJAX request you add a key and value that describe the content i.e: 'content type':'application/json'

So simply, on the server side, you can test the header if it contains application/json as the content type then you are safe to say it's an ajax request.

```
req.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json'
```